# how to navigate different pages by curved navigation bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i can't able to use curved navigation bar in flutter, when i slide screen so buttons of curved navigation bar are also moving but when i tap on buttons of curved navigation bar nothing happens . i think **onTap()** didn't work properly. how to navigate pages when i tap buttons?
here is the code of my program=>

```
  static final String id = 'profile_page';
  @override
  _PagesState createState() => _PagesState();
}

class _PagesState extends State<Pages> {
  PageController _pageController;

  int _Page=0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

        body: PageView(

            controller: _pageController,
          children: <Widget>[

            Search(),
            Trending(),
            Friends(),
            Profile(),
          ],
          onPageChanged: (int index) {
            setState(() {

              _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
            });
          }
          ),


          bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
            animationCurve: Curves.easeInOutBack,

            index:3,

            items: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.search, size: 30, color: Colors.white, ),
              Icon(Icons.trending_up, size: 30, color: Colors.white),
              Icon(Icons.group, size: 30, color: Colors.white),
              Icon(Icons.person, size: 30, color: Colors.white)
            ],
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            height: 60.0,
            onTap: (int index) {
             setState(() {
               _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
             });
            },

          ),
        );

  }
}
```

Comment: now, onTap() works properly but page slide didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

I use it this way:

1. Create a list and a variable that holds current Page no. Here 3 classes can be stateless or statefull widgets.

   ```
   final List<Widget> _tabItems = [Class1(), Class2(), Class3()];
   int _activePage = 0;
   ```
2. Define your body like this:

   ```
   body: _tabItems[_activePage], //Customise it as you want.
   ```
3. Then in your onTap:

   ```
   onTap: (index) {
      setState(() {
        _activePage = index;
      });
    },
   ```

Hope it helps! Happy Coding:)

Answer (score 1):

If you change the page of the `PageView`, you are telling the `CurvedNavigationBar` to change its page. But when you change the page of the `CurvedNavigationBar` you aren't telling the `PageView` to change its page.

You need to add a `PageController` to the `PageView`, like this:

```
final _pageController = PageController();

PageView(
  controller: _pageController,
  ...
```

Then you should be able to do this:

```
_pageController.jumpToPage(index);
```

But make sure when you tell one to change the page of the other, the other doesn't tell again the first one to change its page, because it will be an infinite loop.

Comment: now, onTap() works properly but page slide didn't work.

Comment: What changes did you make? You just added the controller to the PageView and jumpToPage in onTap()?

Comment: i edit my question then you see what changes i make

Comment: It was okay how you were doing the onPageChanged, you just had to change the onTap.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace
`_pageController = PageController();` with

`final _pageController = PageController();`

and remove `_pageController = PageController();` in the *void initState()* method.

No use of `int _Page=0;`
You will be fine.