# Navigating with curved navigation bar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bottomnavigationview

I am using curved bottom navigation bar and I want everytime to have an option selected as default just for the look(e.g Home button) although I want the user to have the ability to tap it.But when I select as default the user hasn't. What can I do?

```
class MainClass extends StatelessWidget{
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  body: MyRV(),
  bottomNavigationBar:CurvedNavigationBar(
    height: 50,
    index: 1,
    color: Colors.orange,
    buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
    backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    items: <Widget>[
      Icon(Icons.arrow_back, size: 20,color: Colors.blueAccent,),
      Icon(Icons.home, size: 20,color: Colors.blueAccent,),
      Icon(Icons.contact_mail, size: 20,color: Colors.blueAccent,),
    ],
    animationDuration:Duration(
      milliseconds: 1000
    ),
    animationCurve: Curves.linearToEaseOut,
    onTap: (index) {
      if (index==1)
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context){return 
    b_afandou();})
        );
      },
    ),
   );
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the question is still getting viewed, so I would like to tell you that it was just a bug I guess. Cause I didn't do anything and it started working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have already implement that. Here `index: 1` means you have set default button as the button corresponding to index 1.

Check this for more details. 
[Corrected way to implement curved navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58480722/how-to-navigate-different-pages-by-curved-navigation-bar-in-flutter/60803922#60803922)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are navigation to different route instead of view. Use

```
body:[yourWidget1,yourWidget2,yourWidget3][_currentIndex]
```

```dart
class MainClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MainClass> createState() => _MainClassState();
}

class _MainClassState extends State<MainClass> {
  int _currentIndex = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: [///this will hold your three page
          Text("First View "),
          Text("second/middle View "),
          Text("Thired  View "),
        ][_currentIndex],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        height: 50,
        index: _currentIndex,
        color: Colors.orange,
        buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        items: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            size: 20,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.home,
            size: 20,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.contact_mail,
            size: 20,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
        ],
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
        animationCurve: Curves.linearToEaseOut,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

More about [`curved_navigation_bar`](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar)